# The horribility of English language

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives, suffixes, morphology

Pretty much every adjective that ends in the suffix *-able* or *-ible* gives rise to a related noun:

- *corruptible* becomes *corruptibility*
- *mutable* becomes *mutability*
- *respectable* becomes *respectability*
- *irritable* becomes *irritability*
- *gullible* becomes *gullibility*

There are only two exceptions, as far as I'm aware: we have *horrible* and *terrible*, but no *horribility* or *terribility*. Now why would that be?

These words seem to have another strange aspect to them. If something is *irritable* then it is not *able to irritate* but *inclined to be irritated*. If I am *respectable* then I'm not *able to respect*, but *inclined to be respected*. The *-able* ending does not generally denote ability.

But *horrible* doesn't mean *inclined to be horrified*; it really does mean *able to horrify*. And *terrible* doesn't mean *inclined to be terrified*; it means *able to terrify*. In other words, these two exceptions to the rule about cognate nouns also seem to be exceptions with respect to what type of property they describe.

Are these two oddities related somehow?

Comment: There's already _horror_ and _terror_, so the need for newly nouned adjectives is low.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cognate'? CDO, for instance, has a definition that would only allow cross-language cognates.

Comment: 'Horribleness' and 'terribleness' are given by AHDEL; they are from the same stable as the adjectives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, maybe cognates have to be cross-language, yes. I've edited the question to get rid of the word. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying that that's the only definition. The word seems ill-defined, even for its linguistics usages.

Comment: Many *-able/-ible* words have *-ableness* forms - [*miserableness*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22miserableness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), for example. I expect at least some people find *favorableness, favorability* both perfectly acceptable (and perhaps distinguishable).

Comment: *Corrupt*, *respectful*, *irritating* are also adjectives whereas gullible is a back formation of *gullibility* i.e. first the word [cullability](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Grose-VulgarTongue/c/cullability.html) existed, then the -c became a -g, and then an adjectival form was created ad-hoc. The meanings of words mutate over time. I think, without realizing it, your question would need a long long answer. Then as John lawyer pointed out, we do have *(n) horror-->horrified* and *(n) terror-->terrified*

Comment: All of these well-stated points add up to the indecipherability of the English language. I would be a fool to argue with you, as I have no answers as to why it is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to agree with Papa Poule that the question arises from a false analysis: *horrible* and *terrible* are not *-able*/*-ible* words in quite the sense you describe, and the corresponding noun derivation doesn't apply.

Off the top of my head, I'd say *ostensible* might be placed in this group, and there may well be others. Conceivably the distinction could come from being words adapted from existing Latin constructions (*horribilis* etc), rather than constructed later from English elements (so the verb in question is *horreo* rather than *horrify*, etc). Although that's just a guess, so almost certainly wrong...

Comment: Just a guess, maybe, but worthy of my upvote for making sense of and, more importantly, for clarifying and putting some substance behind my observation.

Answer (score 0):

First, that's some good research & discovery there.

The *-xble* suffixes are irrelevent to the Q. and distract.
The thing to bring out is the other contender to *-ity:* the *-ness* suffix and how it differs, and thus gives *-ity* a run for its money.

*-ity* is essentially qualitative: tells the nature of sth. *-ness* is quantitative, showing the extent (of even a quality).

Now in the OP's two example cases, *-ity* has little use, and as such seldom seen. It's not, however, ungrammatical. The use of this suffix as in the title here too, may be incorrect: *horribleness* is what's meant.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your analysis of 'horrible' and 'terrible' concerning what type of property they describe that you go/junp from 'horrible' to 'horrify' and from 'terrible' to 'terrify', whereas the other examples do not require (benefit from) such (subjective, perhaps) word modification.

Working backwards from horrify and terrify, we could get 'horrifiable/horrifiability' and 'terrifiable/terrifiabiliy', which, if English words, would not be exceptions to either of the rules that you discuss.  I'm certainly not trying to start a movement to coin these words, but I think the oddities pointed out in your question might have something to do with the fact that not all definitions of 'horrible' and 'terrible' involve things that 'horrify' or 'terrify.'