# -able & -ability usage: Why can't "searchability" be a word? (Or can it?)

Tags: word-usage, suffixes, derivational-morphology, nominalizations

Sometimes I edit a question title on Stack Exchange in order to make it more clear and easier for users to find it when searching. In the comment field I usually enter: "Title edited for clarity and searchability." I think it gets the point across succinctly, and I don't really feel compelled to change it to something like: "Title edited for clarity, and so that the question can be found more easily by search engines." That just feels unnecessarily verbose and forced.

I realize that *searchability* is not in any official dictionaries (to my knowledge), and that I'm taking a liberty here. But what is puzzling to me is that [there does exist the root form "searchable"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/searchable).

I suppose what I'm really getting at is: Why can't *-able* suffix words automatically be converted to *-ability* words? It seems to me that any *-able* word could, as far as meaning is concerned, have an *-ability* counterpart and this would still make sense. Or is there a rule that prohibits this?

I finally got curious enough about this that I had to ask. Thanks for humoring me.

Comment: I personally agree and think searchability is a prefectly reasonable and understandable word.  Interestingly, when I went on the wiktionary page for the suffix -ability, it included a list of words with the suffix.  Many of these words are also not in dictionaries and I have never heard them before.  I have to wonder if there is any rule at all for this.  It seems these words come from Middle English, Middle French, and Latin.  Could it be there is no discernible rule left in Modern English for which words CAN use this suffix and which words CANNOT?

Comment: The OED added it in 2009 ("Now chiefly with reference to electronic data: the quality of being searchable; the degree to which something may be searched"), with 5 citations from 1946 to 2008, so I'd expect to see it in other dictionaries in the near future. However, a minor quibble (since you came to an English Language & Usage site, where we're persnickety about these things)—I think what you really mean is ***findability*** (just added in March 2017): "The quality or fact of being findable; capability of being found. In recent use esp. with reference to the use of online search engines."

Comment: @1006a Thanks for that extra info, and the good point about "findability". I had considered findability as well, however for me personally the idea of whether you can perform a search and whether you will actually find what you are looking for are two separate, albeit similar ideas. Because I make this distinction in my mind, "searchability" makes sense to me in more contexts than "findability". That's just my take on it.

Comment: @Mentalist from the programming perspective, something stored in a database (such as these questions) may or may not be *findable* but that's only relevant if the database is *searchable.* E.g. if the questions were only listed by question number, the titles and bodies and answers etc. would not be searchable at all, clear wording notwithstanding.

Comment: "Searchability" is in [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/searchability) (essentially it is listed as a derivative of "searchable").

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Searchability" is correctly formed, although not common. The [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=searchability%2Csearchable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csearchability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csearchable%3B%2Cc0) shows some minor usage in recent years (the rate of increase seems to grow a bit with the advent of search engines in the 1990s).

The suffix *-ability* is reasonably productive in modern English, which means that it can be used to form new words. It is used to derive nouns corresponding to adjectives ending in *-able* that are ultimately derived from verbs (in this case, the verb *search*). Deriving nouns from other kinds of words is called "nominalization". (A side note: it's not entirely clear to me whether we can say that *-ability* nouns are derived "from" *-able* adjectives, or if we should view *-ability* as a kind of complex suffix used to derive nouns from verbs "in one step" without necessarily going through an intermediate adjective. Perhaps both of these are over-simplified descriptions of the details. But some kind of derivation is definitely involved somehow.)

*[Making New Words: Morphological Derivation in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=O7w8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA305&lpg=PA305&dq=able%20ability%20derivation%20nominalization&source=bl&ots=NxDxsQ7HRX&sig=Ct-yaX1qL1rgM2pJI69RvULEtFg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK_vy2-dDWAhWLw1QKHeGVBrgQ6AEIUTAG#v=onepage&q=able%20ability%20derivation%20nominalization&f=false),* by Robert M. W. Dixon (2014), mentions this pattern, and a few rules of thumb for when *-ability* is most often used vs. *-ableness.* Dixon says that *-ability* is generally only an option when the derived word is understood to refer to some kind of 'potential'. For example, since the word *comfortable* usually means "giving comfort" rather than "able to be comforted", the usual corresponding nominalization is *comfortableness,* not **comfortability.*

Other *-able* adjectives that seem to correspond for the most part to nominalizations in *-ableness* rather than *-ability* are *reasonable, reasonableness;* *miserable, miserableness;* and *charitable, charitableness*.

(But interestingly, *reasonability* and *charitability,* although incredibly rare, do seem to have become a bit more frequent, both in absolute terms and relative to *reasonableness* and *charitableness,* in the past century judging from the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reasonability%2Freasonableness%2Ccharitability%2Fcharitableness&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28reasonability%20/%20reasonableness%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28charitability%20/%20charitableness%29%3B%2Cc0). I don't know if that has any significance—I do remember reading somewhere recently, I don't remember where, that *-ability* became established as a productive nominalizing suffix in English more recently than *-able* became established as a productive adjective-forming suffix, so it seems possible to me that the use of *-ability* may still be "on the rise" in a minor way. Also, *[miserableness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391091/is-suffix-ness-ok),* although better than **miserability,* is not used very often because the noun *misery* expresses much the same idea in most contexts.)

#### Reference about how *-ability* became productive

While I don't believe it is the same source that I said above that I remembered reading, I came across the following relevant information in *[A History of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=BroBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT266&lpg=PT266&dq=phrasal%20verbs%20suffix%20able%20reliable&source=bl&ots=dhPkH3sHT2&sig=RBeoJH1-CZ6K69Te6Si1pa2PwOo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsvOTDq9rWAhUKxoMKHe3MA44Q6AEIRDAF#v=onepage&q=phrasal%20verbs%20suffix%20able%20reliable&f=false),* by Barbara M. H. Strang (2015).

Strang says "-able" was established as a productive suffix for forming adjectives from English verbs by the 1500s, during the period Strang refers to as "III", from 1570-1370 (Strang uses reverse chronological order) (§112). Shortly after period "III", *-ability* became a productive suffix, as shown by its use on native verb stems in words such as "lovability" (behavior that we don't see for other *-ity* nominalizations).

#### Note about the meaning of "searchability" in particular

1006a made a good point in a comment about the meaning of "searchability". It would regularly mean "ability to be searched", not "ability to be searched *for*", and so we would talk about the "searchability" of e.g. a database, not of a piece of data (like a title). There are some "-able" adjectives and "-ability" nouns that have different semantics, like "reliable/reliability" (meaning "able to be relied on/ability to be relied on") and "dependable/dependability", but those are exceptional, and apparently "reliable" in particular was criticized for this reason in the past:

> Use of the word was heavily criticized in the 19th and early 20th centuries, particularly on the grounds that it represented a supposedly irregular formation (although a number of similar formations were already in existence; compare for example available adj. II., dependable adj., dispensable adj., laughable adj.). For a full contemporary discussion see F. Hall *On English Adjectives in -able, with special reference to Reliable* (1877), and see also the following:
>
> > 1996   R. W. Burchfield *New Fowler's Mod. Eng. Usage* (ed. 3) 665   Earlier objection to the word was based on the belief that *reliable* ought to mean ‘able to rely’ rather than ‘able to be relied on’. As Alford (1864) expressed it: ‘*Reliable* is hardly legitimate. We do not *rely a man,* we *rely upon a man;* so that reliable does duty for *rely-upon-able.* *“Trustworthy”* does all the work required.’

(OED)

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for clarifying the issue with your answer, and for improving the searchability of my question by adding relevant tags.

Comment: Related question about words ending in "-able"/"-ible" that don't have corresponding nouns in "-ability"/"-ibility": [The horribility of English language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202855)